# Adjust X to strengthen the linearity to Y, in regression model

Tags: st.statistics, oc.optimization-and-control, convex-optimization, linear-regression

Assume that we have 2 series X and Y, and obvious we can fit a linear regression model and get all the statistics. I am seeking for some transformation / adjustment which will adjust the value of X, so that the linearity between Y and X is stronger (not necessary to be perfect linear but need to strengthen the linearity). A common idea is that we can find the implied x from the real value y and the coefficient from regression and change according to it, i.e.
$$ 
x^{*}_{i} = \frac{y_{i} - \beta{0}}{\beta_{1}} 
$$.
wondering if there are more interesting ideas? And what if I want to keep the order of the original x series?

Comment: The problem would be more understandable if you joint to the question an example of data (numerical, not graphical).